# Error in order clause of partition by when using multiple case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle12c

I want to use multiple case statement inside order by clause in partition by statement.
I have many columns so ,I am only posting the required one.

I have table customers which has:

```
Select
   name,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY lastname, rollno 
ORDER BY
   CASE
      WHEN
         NVL(gender, address) IS NULL 
      then
         a.effdate desc 
      else
         CASE
            WHEN
               NVL(a.postoffc, a.mon) <= file.effdate 
            then
               file.effdate 
            else
               a.postoffc 
         END
         desc, NVL(l4.covcode, a.pass) 
   end
)
rn 
from
   customers a;
```

If,i remove these case statement then my join with other tables and query is working fine.So,there is no problem in join statement or any other logic.The problem I get is when i used multiple case statement.I think my syntax is mistake.Please tell me how can solve this error.I need this case statement logic as mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the second `CASE` block *before* you declare the other ordering criteria. Also, you have an unwanted `DESC` within the expression, that should be placed *after* it.

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN NVL(gender, address) IS NULL THEN a.effdate
        ELSE CASE
            WHEN NVL(a.postoffc, a.mon) <= file.effdate THEN file.effdate 
            ELSE a.postoffc 
        END
    END desc,  --> here
    NVL(l4.covcode, a.pass)
```

But overall, I don't think that you need to nest the `case` expressions. This should work equally well, and is easier to follow:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN NVL(gender, address) IS NULL THEN a.effdate
        WHEN NVL(a.postoffc, a.mon) <= file.effdate THEN file.effdate 
        ELSE a.postoffc 
    END desc, 
    NVL(l4.covcode, a.pass)
```

Comment: Need one clarification here whether the condition `NVL(gender, address) IS NULL` is checked to be valid against each row under the partition or just any row fulfilling this criteria will make it valid?